# Pandas regex row by row

Tags: python, pandas, regex

i' m here to describe my problem: i have to do a lot of change in my pandas dataframe. To be clearer i try to explain better. I have a pandas dataframe of shape (1914163, 16). Among this columns, there is one column named ' MODELLO' which has a lot of values that i have to normalize. Saying normalize i mean that there are a lot of values that have the same meaning, but written in different way. I just want to group this values for 'FAMIGLIA'. So i hope to have explained the problem in a clear way. The dataset seems like:

[image: Dataset]

For example i want that all the model that are like 'RC998-995' are changed into 'RC998' and all 'CESPRO 998 CI' models are changed into 'RO998CI'.
In order to do that i wrote a basic function

```py
def sub_roller(x):
    replace = [(r'(RC+\d*)+-+\d*', r'\1'), (r'(CESPRO 998 CI)',r'RO998CI')]
    for pat, repl in replace:
        x = re.sub(pat, repl, x)
    return x
```

However when i try to do:

```py
df['FAMIGLIA'] = df['MODELLO'].apply(sub_roller)
```

I find in the 'MODEL' column also the family 'WIN' for example, that is to say one of the family that i wouldn't write in the 'FAMIGLIA' column because it is an unchanged value.

This type of behavior is possible with this line of code:

```py
df.loc[df['MODELLO'].str.contains(r'(RC+\d*)+-+\d*', na=False, regex=True), 'FAMIGLIA'] = 'RC998'
```

But in this case i have to write 'RC998' because i can't use the regex form r'\1' to identify the group. By the way I should do this with all types of substitutions and it seems to be a very not optimized way to do what i would.
I hope to have been clear, providing also a clear example of what i'm doing and what i would to obtain. However in any case i'm here to provide any type of detail. Thank you for your support and for the time you'll want to spent for me.

Comment: Maybe [`pd.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)? See the last examples using dictionaries and regex.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write code which I assume would fit your need:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def replacer(arg):
    result = pd.NA
    if match := re.search(r'(RC+\d*)+-+\d*', arg):
        result = match.group(1)
    elif match := re.search(r'CESPRO 998 Cl', arg):
        result = "R0998Cl"
    return result

print(replacer("RC998-995"))
print(replacer("CESPRO 998 Cl"))
print(replacer("WIN"))
```

and it generates following output:

```
RC998
R0998Cl
<NA>
```

which can be later used in method apply()

Comment: You help me to better understand how i could move. Thank you man, I have to improve this solution because in some cases the patterns are more than 10 and i have to think how to process all in the best possible way, but you provided me a good start point